Way to Change URL of a Web Page by keeping contents of Page intact
The structure of my project is as follows:

Test_Repo/public/index.html
Test_Repo/app/class/view/sign-in.html

Currently, the index.html file (inside the Test_Repo/public folder) contains a link that redirects to Test_Repo/app/class/view/sign-in.html.
However, I want the URL in the browser to display as Test_Repo/sign-in.html instead of the full path to the file (Test_Repo/app/class/view/sign-in.html). Importantly, I need to ensure that the contents of the sign-in.html page remain intact and functional while showing only the simplified URL.
[Project structure] (https://i.sstatic.net/H3qcQlwO.png)
I attempted to use .htaccess to achieve this redirection, but the code I wrote seems too complicated. I’m looking for an easier approach to accomplish this while keeping the folder structure the same.
Here is the current content of my .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect requests to the index.html in the public folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/[a-z]+/?){1}$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Test_repo/public/


What exactly do you mean by "the code I wrote seems too complicated"? The code consists of a single rewriting rule. What is complicated about that? Complicated compared to what scale? To what alternative?

Complicated in sense as in it was stopping redirection to my index.html page inside public folder,this htaccess code only redirects to index.html file,htaccess code that was supposed to redirect(now removed) was causing page to redirect too many times
